# Mlogloss value in catboost starts negative and increases

Tags: loss-function, multiclass-classification, mlogit, catboost

I am running catboost classifier with catboost using settings:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=1000, learning_rate=0.05, depth=7, loss_function='MultiClass',calc_feature_importance=True)
```

I have 5 classes and it starts from -ve values and increases as below while fitting model:

```
0:      learn: -1.5036342       test: -1.5039740        best: -1.5039740 (0)    total: 18s      remaining: 4h 59m 46s
1:      learn: -1.4185548       test: -1.4191364        best: -1.4191364 (1)    total: 37.8s    remaining: 5h 14m 24s
2:      learn: -1.3475387       test: -1.3482641        best: -1.3482641 (2)    total: 56.3s    remaining: 5h 12m 1s
3:      learn: -1.2868831       test: -1.2877465        best: -1.2877465 (3)    total: 1m 15s   remaining: 5h 12m 32s
4:      learn: -1.2342138       test: -1.2351585        best: -1.2351585 (4)    total: 1m 34s   remaining: 5h 13m 56s
```

Is this normal behaviour? While in most of the machine learning algorithms, logloss is positive and decreases with training. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behaviour.

When you specify `loss_function='MultiClass'` in parameters of your model, it uses another loss function, not LogLoss, for optimisation. The definition can be found [here](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/loss-functions-docpage/#loss-functions__multiclassification).

To understand the sign of that function, you can think of the best-case scenario and the worst-case scenario. In the best-case the value of the target function for object *a<sub>i</sub>* is all concentrated in the correct class *t*, so the fraction in the *log* (in the formula on the linked page) would equal 1, and the *log* would be 0. However, when you diverge from that best-case, the fraction in the *log* would decrease towards 0, and the *log* itself would get more and more negative.